# Nth-root of unity for representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

*Let $\phi : G \to \mathbb{C^{*}}$ be a representation. Suppose that $g \in G$ has order $n$. Show that $\phi (g)$ is an nth-root of unity. (i.e., a solution to the equation $z^{n} = 1$)*

Since $g$ has order $n$, then $g^{n} = 1$. Thus, we know that, $$\phi (1) = \phi (g^{n}) = \phi (g*...*g) = \phi (g) *...* \phi (g) = \phi (g)^{n}$$ 
Is the development correct? If $\phi(1) = 1 $ it's proved. But how to prove it?

Comment: A group homomorphism must take the identity to the identity: see [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Group_Homomorphism_Preserves_Identity).

Comment: Clarified, thank you.